# How to decrease current time minutes 10 interval for each using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

In Myscenario, I am trying to generate the time list with 10 minutes intervals. I am using below code but not able to achieve exactly.

```
  const date = new Date(timeStamp * 1000);
  let labels = [];
  let hour = date.getHours();
  const interval = 10;

      if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        changeSuffix();
      }
      for (let i = hour; i > hour - 6; i--) {
        if (i !== 0) date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - interval);
        if (i === -1) changeSuffix();
        if (i === 12) labels.push(`${i}PM`);
        else if (i < 1) labels.push(`${i + 12}${suffix}`);
        else labels.push(`${i}${suffix}`);
      }
```

Current Output: `[8PM, 9PM, 10PM, 11.00PM] //Current time 11.00PM should be last index.`

Expected Output: `[10.30PM, 10.40PM, 10.50PM, 11.00PM] //Current time 11.00PM should be last index.`

Comment: Is there a reason you [deleted your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755273/decrease-times-as-strings-for-every-10-minutes-from-current-time-by-using-java) and posted a duplicate of that one here?  That's [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305855/is-it-legit-to-delete-and-repost-a-question-that-gets-no-answers).  Ideally you should have edited that one if there was something about it that needed to change.

Comment: That's what I was asking for. But why did you delete your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755273/decrease-times-as-strings-for-every-10-minutes-from-current-time-by-using-java) instead of updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 12h format you can do

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true }))
// "12:15 PM"
```

If you want to separate the hours from minutes with a dot, you can just replace the `:`

```
.replace(':', '.')
```

And for your loop, you need the current to time be the last index, so for the first iteration you don't want to increment the interval

```
const interval = 10;
const date = new Date();
// round down the minutes
date.setMinutes(Math.floor(date.getMinutes() / 10) * 10);
const labels = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  if (i !== 0) date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - interval);
  
  const label = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true }).replace(':', '.').replace(' ', '');
  // unshift to "push" at the beginning instead of at the end of array 
  labels.unshift(label);
}
console.log(labels);
//   [ "11.50AM", "12.00PM", "12.10PM", "12.20PM" ]
```

Comment: great answer but the problem is array data is showing me 5.10, 5.10, 5.10 by using above code. My array formate is  earlier like this labels.push(`${i}${suffix}`);. May be that's the issue or iteration of 4 times not working properly,

Comment: My answer is based on the code you submitted with your question, and it works in isolation. If you copy and paste it into the browers console, it is working.
If you are having trouble integrating it with other code, you should update your question to add more details.
Your original code already uses Date methods such as `getMinutes` and `setMinutes` so I assumed your data is already a Date object. If it isn't, you can convert it first.

Comment: yeah I am sorry, I have updated my code. above one which is I used for hours but I tried to update as per my expected output but not getting idea. can you please check it once?

Comment: When using the Date object with your `new Date(timeStamp * 1000)` you don't nee to worry with the suffix or wrapping dates. When adding or subtracting the minutes, the Date object already correctly handles the edge cases of changing hours and days, and the `changeSuffix` is unnecessary.
If you need a fixed number of elements in the array, there is also absolutely no need to iterate from the current `hour` instead of a fixed loop

Comment: thank you for your answer but your code will provide output like this[10.30PM, 10.40PM, 10.50PM, 11.00PM] //Current time 11.00PM should be last index.?

Comment: It does provide an output like that.
You can just test the provided code to verify yourself.

Comment: I ran your code output is coming like this [ '5.36PM', '5.46PM', '5.56PM', '6.06PM' ] but can I get roundoff like [ '5.30PM', '5.40PM', '5.50PM', '6.00PM' ]?

Comment: Sure, I updated the code to round them down, as per the example in your comment to round down `6.06PM` to `6.00PM`

Comment: I rounded down based on your comment. If you need to round to nearest 10, you can replace the `Math.floor` with `Math.round`.  Them 06 minutes will be rounded to 10, but 04 will be rounded to 00.

Comment: may I know the reason, why 04 will be rounded to 00?

Comment: your the master. great logic thank you friend :)

Comment: With `Math.floor(value / 10) * 10`, we are always rounding down, because `Math.floor` rounds down to the nearest integer. E.g.: 16 minutes -> 16/10 = 1.6 -> Math.floor(1.6) = 1 -> 1 * 10 -> 10 minutes.
`Math.round` rounds to the nearest integer, so 0.4 rounds to 0 and 0.5 rounds to 1.
E.g.: 16 minutes -> 16/10 = 1.6 -> Math.round(1.6) = 2 -> 2*10 = 20 minutes. And finally
04 minutes -> 04/10 = 0.4 -> Math.round(0.4)  = 00 minutes

Comment: I am facing issue, when I am running into mobile it is showing full timestamp.Its because of const label = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true });